# Need to combine and convert data in paragraph format to csv

Tags: python, parsing, export-to-csv

I am new to Python and am starting some online courses. I am trying to convert some data from a paragraph format to CSV format (shown below.) I am able to import a text file containing the paragraph format and export that to CSV but each line in the paragraph format comes in as a single line when imported into a spreadsheet.

```
import csv
import glob
import os

directory = raw_input("INPUT Folder:")
output = raw_input("OUTPUT Folder:")

txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')

for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
    with open(txt_file, "rb") as input_file:
        in_txt = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='=')
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(txt_file))[0] + '.csv'

        with open(os.path.join(output, filename), 'wb') as output_file:
            out_csv = csv.writer(output_file)
            out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

I do not know how to parse the data to separate the labels and spaces from the numeric values and combine each paragraph section into a single line with quotes and commas for the CSV file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Paragraph format:

12-03-06 15:19:36
FLOW: 1.17365  g/m
POS:   +9273x1Gal

12-03-06 15:19:37
FLOW: 1.17849  g/m
POS:   +9283x1Gal

12-03-06 15:19:38
FLOW: 1.19849  g/m
POS:   +9293x1Gal

(repeats)

Desired CSV output (note, I had to add a single quote before the + to allow proper import as text into a spreadsheet, otherwise it comes in as a 0)

"12-03-06 15:19:36","FLOW:","1.17365","g/m","POS:","'+","9273","x1","Gal"
"12-03-06 15:19:37","FLOW:","1.17849","g/m","POS:","'+","9283","x1","Gal"
"12-03-06 15:19:38","FLOW:","1.19849","g/m","POS:","'+","9293","x1","Gal"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `collections.deque` to work on three lines at a time, and `re.match` to parse out the items you want:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import deque
import csv
from functools import partial
import glob
import os
import re
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
    open_csv_write = partial(open, mode="wb")
else:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input
    open_csv_write = partial(open, mode="w", newline="")

POS_REG = re.compile("(POS:) ([+-])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(x\d+)(\w+)", re.I)

def change_ext(fn, new_ext):
    """
    Given `fn` as "path\filename.old_ext",
      return "path\filename" + new_ext
    """
    return os.path.splitext(fn)[0] + new_ext

def get_pos(line, reg=POS_REG):
    """
    Given a string like "POS: +92.73x1Gal",
      return ['POS:', '+', '92.73', 'x1', 'Gal']
    """
    match = reg.match(line)
    return list(match.groups()) if match else []

def process(inf, outcsv):
    # line queue
    q = deque(maxlen=3)
    # preload two lines
    q.append(next(inf, '').rstrip())
    q.append(next(inf, '').rstrip())
    # process rest of lines
    for line in inf:
        q.append(line.rstrip())
        if q[1].startswith('FLOW:'):
            pos = get_pos(line)
            if pos:
                row = [q[0]] + q[1].split() + pos
                outcsv.writerow(row)

def main():
    # get directories
    in_dir  = inp("Input directory: ")
    out_dir = inp("Output directory: ")

    # process file names
    in_filespec    =  os.path.join(in_dir, '*.txt')
    in_full_names  =  glob.glob(in_filespec)
    in_names       = [os.path.basename(fn)      for fn in in_full_names]
    out_names      = [change_ext(fn, ".csv")    for fn in in_names]
    out_full_names = [os.path.join(out_dir, fn) for fn in out_names]

    # operate on files
    for in_name, out_name in zip(in_full_names, out_full_names):
        with open(in_name) as inf, open_csv_write(out_name) as outf:
            outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
            process(inf, outcsv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hugh, thank you so much for the time you spent to help me! I tested your code on a file that contained 5 'paragraphs" of data as shown in my original post.  The script did indeed ask for the input file folder (containing one file called BE.txt) and an output folder and did create a single BE.csv file.  However, when opening the CSV file in a text editor the contents are not CSV format (looking maybe like a binary file). I am probably missing something. I am using Python 2.7.9 and IDLE on a Windows 7 PC. No errors were reported during processing.

Comment: Hugh,I am wrong about the CSV format. The binary looking code was actually added to the output file only after trying to open the file using OpenOffice Calc.  Retesting today, prior to trying to open the file with OpenOffice, I see that the output file is actually 0 bytes. So an empty file is created.  Do I have the wrong version of Python for this to work?

Comment: Anyone else have a thought on this? I have tried to dissect the code and it looks to me like it should work, but output file is 0 bytes.

Comment: @Paul: could you send a sample file? hugh_bothwell at hot mail dot com

Comment: @Paul: I found the problem; in your example above you show `POS: +9273x1Gal` (one space following `POS:`) but in the sample file you have `POS:   +9273x1Gal` (multiple spaces following `POS:`). My regular expression expected a single space! If you change it to `"(POS:)\s*([+-])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(x\d+)(\w+)"` the program works properly on multispaced data.